# Google Tag Manager Data Layer on Magento Order Success page

Tags: magento, google-tag-manager, data-layer

I have GTM installed on my Magento Enterprise e-commerce site. What is the procedure to implement a Data Layer to capture transaction order data on the checkout/success page?

I would like to stay away from Magento extensions. Thank you for your time.

Comment: This question is off topic as it's not related directly to coding, but in any case, this resource may help: https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce.

Comment: ok thank you. Sorry about that.

Comment: If you want to implement the dataLayer manually this seems rather strongly related to coding :-) But there is a Magento SO site and you might have more luck there. I have to admin though that I do not understand why you want to avoid extensions, as you will probably end up creating some sort of extension yourself.

Comment: Thanks Eike. I would like to code it manually so I can learn instead of taking the easy way out. Thank you.